# converting date into timestamp in R

Tags: r, timestamp

i've searched for threads about timestamp conversion in R, but could not figure this out.
I need to convert time column into timestamp so R would read it as dates. When the cell has only date without time, there is no problem, but the current format (either with + or without it in the cell - R considers it as integer or factor).
How do i convert it into timestamp?

thank you
[image]

Comment: maybe remove the +, with something like that substr(t, 1, nchar(t)-1) and then convert to date

Comment: removal of + leaves me with 29/11/2014 15:23 instead of 29-11-2014 15:23... i'm missing the conversion to date and time part

Comment: When you say that it's viewing it as an integer or a factor, that leads me to believe that you're reading your data in without setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. This might be why you can't convert it to a date. Otherwise, it should work fine if you pass a valid format argument to `as.Date`

Comment: Nope, you do *not* need to remove it.  See the answer I just added.

Comment: And, and for future reference please _don't include data as a screenshot_.  See [this SO post for why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

You do **not** need to remove the `+`:

```
R> crappyinput <- c("2014-11-29 15:23:02+", "2014-11-29 15:38:36+", 
+                   "2014-11-29 15:52:49+")
R> pt <- strptime(crappyinput, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
R> pt
[1] "2014-11-29 15:23:02 CST" "2014-11-29 15:38:36 CST" "2014-11-29 15:52:49 CST"
R>
```

It will simply be ignored as trailing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

would this work for you?

```
t <- c("2014-11-29 15:23:02+")
t <- substr(t, 1, nchar(t)-1)
t
[1] "2014-11-29 15:23:02"
t <- strptime(t, format="%Y-%m-%d")
str(t)
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2014-11-29"
```

Comment: You don't even have to remove the plus sign. `t <- as.Date("2014-11-29 15:23:02+", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+")` produces the same outcome, although not with a class of `POSIXlt`.